# Angular client retrieve data(URL) from appsetting.json

Tags: json, angular, appsettings

I have an appsettings.json what is out of angular client, its in AppWeb.appsettings.json ... and angular is AppWeb.ClientApp.src ... how can i use link from appsettings.json in my angular app

```
"ImportantLinks": {
    "UrlOne": "https://uefa.com"
  }
```

Comment: Would say not possible. Probably you need to migrate those settings into *environment.ts* as [(Configuring application environments) docs](https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-application-environments). It sounds like this appsettings.json is from the .NET Core project. In that case, you can build an API action to retrieve the configuration and the Angular app to call the API action. But note that this approach may be risky as your configuration is exposed to the public.

Comment: What Yong stated is correct, using environment variables is a good solution if you dont want to expose it. 

But if you want to change it after compilation (for instance on different deployments if you compile once for a docker image), I would suggest to look into "runtime config". Thats how the 2nd part of Yong's solution is called, should help you finding it as there is extensive information on how to implement it.

Comment: Thanks guys. I ended am of adding string parameter to the handler in the autofac.